# iPhone: How to extend a repeatable UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image which I use to frame a tweet. It consists of two rounded rects, with a twitter icon a the top left. The important part is that it is repeatable, as you could copy any part of the middle section vertically, and it would be the same, just longer. Here is the image I created:

[image: Tweet Frame]

My question is how, in code, do I extend (or shrink) that dependent on how many lines are in my UITextView? Something like this to get the size:

```
float requiredHeight = lines * 14;
```

I know this is possible, because apple do it with their SMS app :)

---

**UPDATE:** Here is the complete code for doing this:

```
UIImage *loadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TwitPost.png"];
float w2 = loadImage.size.width/2;
float h2 = loadImage.size.height/2;
// I have now reduced the image size so the height must be offset a little (otherwise it stretches the bird!):
loadImage = [loadImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:w2 topCapHeight:h2+15];
imageView.image = loadImage;
```

Thanks for both answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

Where you set leftCapWidth and topCapHeight as half the width and height of your image. This image you can stretch in a UIImageView by changing its bounds/frame.

Comment: so if you load up a UIImageView with this stretchable image, you can simply alter the frame of that UIImageView and it will change, and won't try to scale it or anything?

Comment: yes. you need to set the image mode to "scale to fill", but indeed the borders will not deform or stretch, it will simply repeat the middle pixels

Comment: Tried - this doesn't work with shrinking, but I'm guessing you simply make the image as small as you need it, and then scale that up?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the documentation for UIImage. Specifically:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

This allows you to use an image which repeats the portion at the leftCapWidth or topCapHeight to stretch it horizontally or vertically.